# In mongoDB how to reach to value of the field "name" in the array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

I need to search how many people have a specific friend (by name) and each records in JSON have an array of friends. How can I reach to the value of the field "name" in the array of objects in mongoDB shell? Maybe this field need to be indexed before perform searches on this field?

```js
"friends" : [{ "id" : 0, "name" : "Baird Fitzpatrick" }, { "id" : 1, "name" : "Karyn Benjamin" }, { "id" : 2, "name" : "Stacey Fuentes" }]
```

[image]

Comment: Put the sample output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search nested object in mongodb by providing a path to nested property:

```
db.YOURCOLLECTION.find({"friends.name": "ABC"});
```

Read more about [nested object query here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/)

> Maybe this field need to be indexed before perform searches on this field?

Of course you're able to create index on nested field. Just provide an index with property is path to nested field like above:

```
db.YOURCOLLECTION.createIndex( { "friends.name": 1 } )
```

For advance usage, you can read about [`$regex` query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: Thank you! But it didn't help even setting { "friends.name": 1 }. I've tried change : 1 to "text" but  I got "IndexOptionsConflict".

db.users.dropIndex( "friends.name" ) - "index not found with name [friends.name]" but it still sit there. @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn

Comment: You do not need to index before querying. The index is just a bonus to query faster. The exception tells you that an index is already there.

Comment: Use db.users.getIndexes() to see what indexes you're currently have.

Comment: Thank you I know about getIndexes(). Why db.users.find({"friends.name": "ABC"});  Didn't show anything?

Comment: You need to replace "ABC" with your name filter XD

Comment: I know it ^))))))

Comment: Then it should work. Ex: db.users.find({"friends.name": "Karyn Benjamin"})

Comment: With full name yes work! but don't work with name or  fullname separately

Comment: To work with part of name, you need to use regex: db.users.find({"friends.name": /Karyn/})

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what I've looked for! @ Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn